# Delegates Vs. Notifications in iPhoneOS

Tags: iphone, delegates, notifications

I am trying to call a method in my root view controller from a child view controller such that when I change my options they will automatically update the root view, which will in turn update several other view controllers.  For the second part I have used notifications, but for this first I am trying to use a delegate because it (so I have been lead to believe) is a good programming practice.  I am having trouble making it work and know that I can set up another notification easily to do the job.  Should I continue trying to implement the delegate or just use a notification?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Delegating is a good programming practice for many situations but that doesn't mean you have to use it if you're not comfortable with it. Both delegating and notifications help decouple the view controllers from each other, which is a good thing. Notifications might be a little easier to code and offer the advantage that multiple objects can observe one notification. With delegates, such a thing cannot be done without modifying the delegating object (and is unusual).

Some advantages of delegating:

- The connection between delegating object and delegate is made clearer, especially if implementing the delegate is mandatory.
- If more than one type of message has to be passed from delegatee to delegate, delegating can make this clearer by specifying one delegate method per message. <del>For notifications, you can use multiple notification names but all notifications end up in the same method on the side of the observer (possibly requiring a nasty switch statement).</del>

Only you can decide what pattern is more appropriate for you. In any case, you should consider not having your view controller send the notification or the delegate message. In many cases, the view controller should change the model and then the model should inform its observers or its delegate that it has been changed.

Implementing a delegate pattern is simple:

1. In your ChildViewController.h, declare the delegate protocol that the delegate must implement later:

   ```
   @protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
   @optional
   - (void)viewControllerDidChange:(ChildViewController *)controller;
   @end
   ```
2. At the top of the file, create an instance variable to hold the pointer to the delegate in your ChildViewController:

   ```
   @protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate;
   @interface ChildViewController : UIViewController {
       id <ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
       ...
   }
   @property (assign) id <ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
   ...
   @end
   ```
3. In RootViewController.h, make your class conform to the delegate protocol:

   ```
   @interface RootViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate> {
   ...
   ```
4. In the RootViewController implementation, implement the delegate method. Also, when you create the ChildViewController instance, you have to assign the delegate.

   ```
   @implement RootViewController
   ...
   // in some method:
   ChildViewController *controller = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:...
   controller.delegate = self;
   ...
   - (void)viewControllerDidChange:(ChildViewController *)controller {
       NSLog(@"Delegate method was called.");
   }
   ...
   ```
5. In the ChildViewController implementation, call the delegate method at the appropriate time:

   ```
   @implementation ChildViewController
   ...
   // in some method:
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllerDidChange:)]) {
       [self.delegate viewControllerDidChange:self];
   }
   ...
   ```

That's it. (Note: I have written this from memory so there are probably some typos/bugs in it.)

Comment: Great answer, was just about to write mine, but yours is really good.

Comment: Fantastic, That did the trick.  When I was just starting out with iPhone OS I went to one of those developer seminars apple had and most of it unfortunately went over my head at the time.  There was a specific diagram they showed about this and now I finally understand it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your second bullet point says that all notifications end up in the same method, but that's not true.  By using `-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]`, you can easily direct different notifications to different methods.

Comment: One more point to note from second bullet point. In the code you have defined the delegate using assign identifier. Which can easily trap to a crash. When strong reference goes from the controller then assign holds some junk value. So better we can use "weak" which will be nil when there are no strong references. Basically it points to nothing and it will not app to crash. And assign meant for primitive data types.

Answer (score 25):

I would like to add:

> objects receiving notifications can
>   react only after the event has
>   occurred. This is a significant
>   difference from delegation. The
>   delegate is given a chance to reject
>   or modify the operation proposed by
>   the delegating object. Observing
>   objects, on the other hand, cannot
>   directly affect an impending
>   operation.

Answer (score 13):

Typically, if you need to update the UI based on a change to data in a model, you would have the view controllers observe the relevant model data and update their views when notified of changes.

I see delegation as a bit more formal and like the distinction that [Peter Hosey](http://www.formspring.me/boredzo) shared recently:

> The difference is that delegation is
>   for to-one (and bidirectional)
>   communication, whereas notifications
>   are for to-many, unidirectional
>   communication.

Also, I have found that (completely) updating the view in `viewWillAppear:` works fine (but this is not the best solution where performance is a concern).

Answer (score 6):

Notifications can make the runtime behavior of your program significantly more complex.  Think of it like a goto with multiple destinations.  The order of those destinations is not defined.  If you ever crash there is little stack trace information.

There are cases when it makes sense to use notifications--the typical one being to communicate a model change or a global state change to your views.  Example, the network is down, the application will resign, etc!

It is worthwhile to learn the delegate pattern in iOS.  Delegates give you complete stack traces when you debug.   They result in significantly simpler runtime behavior while still achieving the goal of decoupling your objects.

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are a little hard to get used to, but I think it's the best practice and, like Apple, *they just work*.

I always use the formal protocol declaration. It's a bit more logical in my mind, and it's very clear in the code. **I suggest using a UIView to change your options instead of a controller. I always use one main controller and have a lot of subclassed UIViews that the one controller can control.** (However, you can modify the following code for a controller, **if you really need a controller instead of a normal view.**) In the header file of the child view, make it look like this:

```
// ChildView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ChildViewDelegate; // tells the compiler that there will be a protocol definition later

@interface ChildViewController : UIView {
    id <ChildViewDelegate> delegate;
    // more stuff
}

// properties and class/instance methods

@end

@protocol ChildViewDelegate // this is the formal definition

- (void)childView:(ChildView *)c willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)i; // change the part after (ChildView *)c to reflect the chosen options

@end
```

The method between `@protocol` and the second `@end` can be called somewhere in the implementation of the ChildView, and then your root view controller can be the delegate that receives the 'notification.'

The .m file should be like this:

```
// ChildView.m
#import "ChildView.h"

@implementation ChildView

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<ChildViewDelegate>)del { // make this whatever you want
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRect(0, 0, 50, 50)]) { // if frame is a parameter for the init method, you can make that here, your choice
        delegate = del; // this defines what class listens to the 'notification'
    }
    return self;
}

// other methods

// example: a method that will remove the subview

- (void)dismiss {
    // tell the delegate (listener) that you're about to dismiss this view
    [delegate childView:self willDismissWithButtonIndex:3];
    [self removeFromSuperView];
}

@end
```

Then the root view controller's .h file would include the following code:

```
// RootViewController.h
#import "ChildView.h"

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewDelegate> {
    // stuff
}

// stuff

@end
```

And the implementation file will implement the method defined in the protocol in ChildView.h, because it will run when the ChildView calls for it to be run. In that method, put the stuff that happens when you'd get the notification.

Comment: My understanding is that many subclasses of UIViewController would be the better approach and that subclassing UIView should be limited to when a custom view (overriding `drawRect:`) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to use either delegation or notification because you don't really need to communicate directly between your views. As gerry3 said, you need to change the data model itself and then let all other views respond to that change.

Your data model should be an independent object that all your view controllers have access to . (The lazy way is to park it as an attribute of the app delegate.) When the user makes a change in View A, View A's controller writes that change to the data model. Then whenever Views B through Z open up, their controllers read the data model and configure the views appropriately.

This way, the neither the views, nor their controllers need to be aware of each other and all changes occur in one central object so they are easily tracked.

Comment: Notifications are a nice way to avoid the overhead of many things repeatedly polling though because they only change when they need to...

Comment: Yes, but in this case the view controllers should be reading the data model when they display the view. Since only one controller is active at any given time there is no reason for controllers to poll the data model. Now is the data model was in constant flux from say a url input, then they would but that is rarely the case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary for your root view controller to know about the changes, or just the subviews?

If the root controller does not have to know, having the settings send out the notifications the other views are looking for seems like a better answer to me, as it simplifies code.  There is no need to introduce more complexity than you have to.