# Issit possible to load a UIVIewcontroller from uiview of another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have:

- an `UIViewController` A
- `UIView` B: I added subview which is a `UIView` to the `UIViewController` A
- an `UIViewController` C

What I did is:

in `UIViewController` A's `viewDidLoad's` method, I call this:

```
UIView *subviewB = [[Subview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[subviewB subviewBMethod]; // 
[self.view addSubview:subviewB];
```

SubviewBMethod code is to create an view, inside this view have a button. Once this button is clicked, it will change to `UIViewController` C.

I tried this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.UIViewControllerC animated:YES];
```

And I got this error message:

> warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIViewControllerC *',
>   expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of
>   'presentModalViewController:animated:' from distinct Objective-C type

When I run the app, it terminates immediately when I click the button, I opened the console bug, there is no any error message. My method must be wrong, thus my question is:

Is it possible to load a `UIVIewcontroller` from `UIView` of another `UIViewController`? If:

- Yes: How to do it?
- No: What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a declaration like this:

```
 UIViewControllerC *UIViewControllerC;
                 ^
```

When you want:

```
 UIViewController *UIViewControllerC;
```

Comment: I think UIViewControllerC really is what he wants, since it is his custom subclass. Declaring it that way will make him have to cast it every time he calls a custom method on his view controller.

Comment: Oh, of course... But isn't it odd that you'd need to coerce it? If it's an subclass of UIViewController, the system would note that, and accept it, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi, I have both declared UIViewController A and C as @property(nonatomic, retain) type, syntesize and release it, but it still have the same warning message. Is it because UIView cant call this function: [self presentModalViewController:self.UIViewControllerC animated:YES];??

Answer (score 1):

I've recently done the same thing. - I have a viewControllerA that has a seeMoreView (a custom view) on it. When the user clicks "see more", viewControllerB is presented.

I solved it like this:

1. I subclassed seeMoreView.
2. I declared a delegate in the seeMoreView - syntax in this answer:
   [Delegates Vs. Notifications in iPhoneOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232694/delegates-vs-notifications-in-iphoneos)
3. In viewControllerA I set the delegate of the seeMoreView as self when creating the view.
4. In viewControllerA I implement the delegate method, which presents viewControllerB.

(I don't think it's good practice in the MVC paradigm to call a view controller from a view.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
[self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)self.UIViewControllerC animated:YES];
```

Comment: What? Are you sure self isn't pointing to a UIViewController? Because that should give a different error. Can you post your exact code so we can check?